# Extract translation data only from a transformation using snap.svg

Tags: svg, snap.svg

I'm making a "geometric transformation" page, designed to be used for teachers. I'm using Snap.svg.

My problem concern the naming of the polygon points. I want to add a name (A, B, C, ...) for each points of the polyon. The problem comes for naming the 'image' polygon, found with a transformation.

If it's a simple translation, then it's not a problem.
But as soon as it rotates, scales or is with a symmetry, it also turns/scales the letters.

Working page (in french, sorry): http://dev.scolcours.ch/_dev/svg_dev_3.php

Basically, to create the polygon and the image, I'm using something similar to:

```
p = s.polygon(points);
img = p.clone();
img.transform(t);
```

Is there a way to get the absolute coordinates of the cloned and transformed img polygon so I can manually place all the point letters ?

What I already tried:

1. Apply the same transformation (string) from polygon to image on the points (it's the version for the linked page above).
2. Use a Matrix instead and extract the dx and dy values (using matrix.split() ). But it does not work too. For the rotation, the points doesn't follow the polygon image. I was using this:

String version:

```
var t = 'r50,60,80';
```

Matrix version:

```
var m = new Snap.Matrix();
m.rotate(50,60,80);
// Then to extract the translation
var mXY = m.split();
var t = 't'+mXY.dx+' '+mXY.dy;
```

I have then something like this:
[image: Image points are at the wrong location]

Hope you'll understand and that you can help me find a solution (without having to calculate manually all the points - which is my last solution).

---

As suggested by Ian, here is a jsFiddle with the rotation only: http://jsfiddle.net/ap1ay4m5/1/

Basil

Comment: It would be helpful if you could put a basic testing example on a jsfiddle, just with an example polygon and letters.

Comment: Btw the answer I suspect may be quite similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33627083/decomposing-svg-transformation-matrix/33629792#33629792 so thats worth a look (look at the jsfiddle I posted there)

Comment: @Ian: I tried using the linked above, using the globalmatrix. But still no luck. The attached fiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net/ap1ay4m5/1/ ) is using the global matrix.

Comment: Realistically you need to break it down further, you can probably remove 90% of that to highlight the fundamental problem, so people don't have to go trawling through all that code to see what may be relevant.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I reduced the code as much as possible (but there is no more dragging abilities). http://jsfiddle.net/ap1ay4m5/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

globalMatrix will give us the full matrix on an element.

The matrix methods matrix.x() and matrix.y() will give us the x,y components.

So we can iterate over the points and get the new values to position...

```
var ptsarray = [];
var pts = img.attr('points')

var m = img.transform().globalMatrix;

for( var c = 0; c < pts.length ; c += 2 ) {     
  img_pts.push(this.text(m.x( pts[c], pts[c+1] ), m.y( pts[c], pts[c+1] ) , nums[c/2].attr('text')).addClass('img_nom'));

}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ian_b/ap1ay4m5/14/)

Comment: I have now another problem, concerning the viewbox. I want to print the SVG with a specific width/height (in cm) but keep the viewBox at 800 x 600 px. The points aren't placed correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/ap1ay4m5/16/

Comment: Try localMatrix rather than globalMatrix eg http://jsfiddle.net/ian_b/ap1ay4m5/17/

Comment: Thanks. It's exactly what I needed! I'm wondering: when will you use a globalMatrix if you have a set viewBox ?

Comment: Suppose you have various nested elements (eg svg or groups) with transforms on them. I would think of it as globalMatrix being the combined outer matrices that have an effect just on the element in question, and localMatrix being the specific matrix applying to that element (with diffMatrix being the difference between the two). So when you use each one, depends whether you are thinking about it in the context of all the combined matrices and outer coordinate space or just whats in the local coordinate space.

Comment: This makes sense. Thanks for the clarification.